# Excel Pivot Chart Help - Pulling names that contributed to count (VBA?)

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking to develop a pivotchart of meaningful data related to employees. Lets say it's a graph of employees with infractions by month.

We have a graph that graphs it based on the COUNT of employees that got an infraction for that month. What I am looking to do is make it very easy for management to see the graph and then see the names that contributed to a large count for a month.

However, upon selecting a certain pivot chart cell (Lets say March had a LOT of infractions on the chart and we want to know who was a part of it). Upon double clicking the cell, it then brings up a "Show Detail" window, we select the cell Name since we want to know the names - however that doesn't help because it just puts the names as part of the legend and screws up the chart.

What are some ways to get it to display the names that contributed to the count for the month? I am thinking something along these lines:
-Upon mousing over the data point of the pivot chart, the tooltip is a list of the names
-Upon clicking on it, it displays a table at the bottom that shows the data from the table that contributed to that month (including names).

Anything along those lines. Any help is much appreciated, I do have experience with VBA - but sadly not in Excel yet.E

Answer (score 0):

The best solution would be to check the PivotTable associated with the PivotChart.

When you show detail on the chart the change will be mirrored in the PivotTable.

For more information check out [Overview of PivotTable and PivotChart reports @ office.microsoft.com](http://office.microsoft.com/en-au/excel-help/overview-of-pivottable-and-pivotchart-reports-HP010177384.aspx)